# Google analytics with adobe AIR app?

Tags: android, air, google-analytics

I have installed the google analytics in my app with gaforflash , and in the debug mode I see that it says it counted pageviews (I added the code to count pageviews for every level) but after 24 hours I don't see a single visint in my analytics profile. Also when I was making the profile on analytics I chose mobile, not website. Should I have gone with website?

Comment: My guess is that you've created a new universal analytics (analytics.js) property, and gaforflash is setup for google analytics (ga.js).

Comment: I know it's possible to use gaforflash with AIR, but I've never been able to successfully do it. In all honesty, I have found it is easiest just to create your own library for it  using the measurement protocol(I would share mine, but can't due to NDAs). All you need can be found here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should have selected website as the profile when using gaforflash.

However you can use a Google Analytics ANE which will work with a mobile profile.
I'm currently doing this.

https://github.com/alebianco/ANE-Google-Analytics